# How to create M2epro Amazon Order Object in Magento 2

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, magento, magento2, m2e-pro

I want to create M2epro Amazon Order object in Magento2.

This is due to some magento orders are not created because of inventory or product status. So I want to programatically create Amazon Order object and call createMagentoOrder().

File - m2epro/magento2-extension/Model/Order.php

Git Link - https://github.com/m2epro/magento2-extension

My Code -

```
$amazonobj = $objManager->get('\Ess\M2ePro\Model\Amazon\Order');

$amazonfactory = $amazonobj->get('\Ess\M2ePro\Model\ActiveRecord\Component\Parent\Amazon\Factory');
```

So after providing inventory and status to enable for product the magento 2 orders should be create.

I want to create Amazon Order object.

Any suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: yes I tried it using amazonFactory but not working.

Answer (score 0):

My Solution -

```
$amazonFactory = $objectManager->create('\Ess\M2ePro\Model\ActiveRecord\Component\Parent\Amazon\Factory');
$order = $amazonFactory->getObjectLoaded('Order', (int)$id);
$order->getLog()->setInitiator(\Ess\M2ePro\Helper\Data::INITIATOR_USER);
```